# dbSendQuery only returning 500 rows when using RMySQL in R

Tags: r, rmysql

I am using `RMySQL` to query a database.

I used

`df <- fetch(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT some_col from some_table"))`

and got back this message:

```
Error in fetch(dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT some_col from some_table")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'res' in selecting a method for function 'fetch': Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  connection with pending rows, close resultSet before continuing
```

Strangely, `df` was actually created; `500 obs. of 1 variables`, and it did give me back what I expected for these 500.

- The table `some_table` has 292,000 rows, which shouldn't be a problem
  at all for R.
- I tried with a variety of other tables in my schema (e.g.,
  `some_other_table`) and got the same result. So it appears to be
  something with respect to the `fetch` function itself.
- I tried using `dbGetQuery` and `dbFetch` with no success.

What does this error mean, and how can I get all the rows in my table?

**FOLLOWUP**

I found out that I can slurp up a whole table by using

`dbReadTable(con, 'some_table')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal behavior. The `RMySQL` implementations retrieves only `n` records, and if `n` is missing it only returns up to `fetch.default.rec` as specified in the call to MySQL (500 by default).

To return all of the rows use `n = -1`.

Also, it's useful to assign a name to your entire query string and then just pass that name to your `fetch()` statement.

```
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user = "username", password="password1", 
                 host = "localhost", dbname="database")
res <- dbSendQuery(con, statement = paste(
                      "SELECT some_column1, some_column2",
                      "FROM some_table", 
                      "WHERE some_column2 >= x",
                      "ORDER BY some_column1"))
data1 <- fetch(res, n = -1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I'm having trouble finding good information about the RMySQL package. Seems like it would be immensely popular and widely used -- but  even on SO, there are only ~175 questions with this tag.

Comment: Strangely, it even seems 'n = -1' is the default setting if you look at the help section or print the source code in the R console.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped so much to use the `RMySQL` package in a useful way :  [Accessing MySQL through R](http://playingwithr.blogspot.com/2011/05/accessing-mysql-through-r.html)

It includes also that you have to pass the parameter `n=-1` to the `fetch` function to retrieve all data and not only the first `500 rows` which is set by default in the `fetch` function.

I hope that helps you like It did for me.

**Other useful links:**

[R interface to the MySQL database](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/RMySQL/html/RMySQL-package.html)

[Accessing MySQL through R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/accessing-mysql-through-r/)